# Netgear Nighthawk x8 R8500 Dual Band and Printing

Tags: wireless-networking, router, printing, dual-band

I have a Netgear Nighthawk x8 R8500 Dual Band router that most all my devices connect to the 5 G channel and a couple of older devices and my new Brother MFG-9330cdw connect via the 2.4 G.  From my computer I cannot see the printer when connected via 5 G.  Is there a way to print wirelessly without switching to the 2.4 channel just to print?

I appreciate any advice.

Comment: A lot of printers these days are able to setup their own wireless connection so that you can print directly to them without the need for a router.  I'm guessing you are connecting directly to the printers wireless network, instead of connecting your printer through your router, and you then accessing your printer through the home network. This is probably why you would have to change to a 2.4GHz channel as the printer would not support a 5GHz connection.

Answer (score -1):

AP Isolation should be turned off.

Comment: "AP Isolation should be turned off." - Why?